# Modbus Conversion of two U16 to a Float

Tags: math, protocols

I have two systems that are passing real numbers to each other.  One receiving system is not converting the two U16s to a float accurately (using an internal function).  An example is 100.15 is being converted into 100.21.  Accuracy is very important to my application.  I need to perform the conversion myself but lack the math to do so.  Can anyone supply the mathematics necessary to convert two Modbus U16s into a float?

Example: Given 123.456 Modbus passes 17142 and 59769

Comment: What code does your receiving system use? I usually just read the modbus field into a byte array, byte swap then memcopy to a float variable. Do you have no control over that aspect of the code?

Comment: The interpretation of Modbus values (i.e.: the value units) are hardware specific, especially for those that represent coordinates. For example, in 0.05mm units. I'd suggest checking the hardware specification documents or for hints about value units.

Comment: The receiving system is a Modicon PLC running ladder logic. Upon further investigation, it is the conversion from two U16s to one U32 that is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The near similarity of the two numbers is odd. If there were a representation problem (bytes swapped, for example) the values would not match, if they could even be interpreted as a valid float.

If you need to be sure about the values, can you get the two systems to move the values in fixed point (100150) for example and divide the number by 1000 to scale it back to engineering units?

This will allow you to avoid the complexity of the floating point implementations in both sender and receiver. Of course, if the scaled integer conversion is the problem, then you will need to look at alternative representations for the values in the system with the problem.